# installing old 32-bit software on latest UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, compiling, make

I'm trying to install legacy software (32-bit) on a 64-bit LINUX HPC cluster.
This is quite old software from 2005.

Software is at https://www.drive5.com/pals/

OS details are `PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"`

make gives:

```
g++ -c -O3 -march=pentiumpro -mcpu=pentiumpro -funroll-loops -Winline -DNDEBUG=1  aligntraps.cpp -o aligntraps.o
g++: warning: ‘-mcpu=’ is deprecated; use ‘-mtune=’ or ‘-march=’ instead
cc1plus: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'aligntraps.o' failed
make: *** [aligntraps.o] Error 1
```

Could someone  advice on how to change the Makefile, shown below, so my software compilation make step will complete successfully?

```
CFLAGS = -O3 -march=pentiumpro -mcpu=pentiumpro -funroll-loops -Winline -DNDEBUG=1
LDLIBS = -lm -static
# LDLIBS = -lm

OBJ = .o
EXE =

RM = rm -f
CP = cp

GPP = g++
LD = $(GPP) $(CFLAGS)
CPP = $(GPP) -c $(CFLAGS) 
CC = gcc -c $(CFLAGS) 

all: pals

CPPSRC = $(sort $(wildcard *.cpp))
CPPOBJ  = $(subst .cpp,.o,$(CPPSRC))

$(CPPOBJ): %.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP) $< -o $@

pals: $(CPPOBJ)
    $(LD) -o pals $(CPPOBJ) $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]!  I'm upvoting this question because it explains the problem clearly and it looks like it could be useful for others in the same situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE - although the title of your question is about "installing old 32-bit software", there seems to be no particular reason not to build the program as native 64-bit software. However if you really do need to build a 32-bit version (for benchmarking, or for exactly reproducing previously published results) then here's how.**

---

Not that my system is 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04 with gcc/g++ 7

```
$ uname -a
Linux t400s 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

In this particular case, the software you are trying to build does not appear to use any libraries beyond `libm.a`, and it appears to be sufficient to install the `g++-multilib` package (which will install `gcc-multilib` and `libc6-dev-x32` as dependencies) and then modify the Makefile's `CFLAGS` to include `-m32`

So

```
sudo apt install g++-multilib
```

Then

```
$ head -3 Makefile 
CFLAGS = -m32 -O3 -march=pentiumpro -mcpu=pentiumpro -funroll-loops -Winline -DNDEBUG=1
LDLIBS = -lm -static
# LDLIBS = -lm

$ make
```

You will get some warnings that

```
g++: warning: ‘-mcpu=’ is deprecated; use ‘-mtune=’ or ‘-march=’ instead
```

however the `pals` program should build:

```
$ file pals
pals: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=1b9e369acf2aa7c6448b4132a203b8dccde16a7d, not stripped
```

and run

```
$ ./pals

PALS v1.0
http://www.drive5.com/pals
Written by Bob Edgar and Gene Myers.
This software is donated to the public domain.
Please visit web site for requested citation.


Usage:
    pals -target <fastafile> -query <fastafile>
    pals -self <fastafile>

Options:
    -out <outfile>       (default standard output)
    -fwdonly             don't align reverse strand
    -filterout <file>    save filter hits to file

Alignment parameters can be specified in three ways:
    (1) Defaults         -length 400 -pctid 94
    (2) Specify -length <minhitlength> -pctid <minhitid>
    (3) Specify all filter and d.p. parameters:
           -wordsize     Filter word size
           -seedlength   Seed hit length
           -seeddiffs    Max #diffs in seed hit
           -length       Min length of final hit
           -pctid        Min %id of final hit
           -tubeoffset   (Optional)

For further information, please see the User Guide.

Must specify either -self or both -target and -query
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked...
I forgot to acknowledge, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing -march=pentiumpro -mcpu=pentiumpro from the Makefile

It compiled it and ran here using a file from here, making that change.

https://molb7621.github.io/workshop/Miscellaneous/data.html

./pals -self sample.fa and got

```
 0 secs       1 Mb (  0%) Reading sequence
 0 secs      12 Mb (  1%) Reading sequence done (0s).
```

Sequence length 3092 bases (0 Mb), 4 contigs

....whole bunch of lines.....

0 DP hits, total length 0
Elapsed time 0 secs, peak mem use 280 M

Comment: Thank you, but steeldriver's response worked, before I got to yours.  Appreciate your help...